# Razor page with existing Database but without Foreign Keys

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am making an intern website with razor Page in .net core 6.
The Database existed already and it used for an other .net application. This database hasn't foreign key and primary key are just technical key. These primary keys are not the field I can used in SQL to link the table.
I follow tutorial, I succeed to scaffolded my models from my database (so whitouth foreign key reference), I succeed to create the simple CRUD pages for my database's tables.
But now I have to make pages which used many tables linked by field, I tried manual configuration in model or in modelbuilder but I failed.

Below you can see the code in example :
In "Category" table the field link to "Document" is Category.Code

```
namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public partial class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; } = null!;
        public string label{ get; set; } = null!;
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In "Document" table the field link to "Category" is Document.CodeCat.
A document is concerned by only one Category.
A Category can reference one or many Documents.

```
namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public partial class Document
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Codecat { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Datedoc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Datedel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use EF Core for this. Use Dapper or plain ADO.NET and execute your own SQL statements.

Comment: Hello, I will check these library. I'm new in .net and C#. There is no way to specify manually to EF the link between two models ? (when there's not foreign key in database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do 2 things:

First, specify the link in the two models, like this:

```
 public partial class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; } = null!;
        public string label{ get; set; } = null!;
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Document
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        public string? Codecat { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set;}

        public DateTime? Datedoc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Datedel { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, specify which fields are used to link the table in the context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasOne(d => d.Category)
            .WithMany(c => c.Documents)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Codecat)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.Code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you Models as below, then Run `Add-Migration` then `Update-database` :

```
 public partial class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; } = null!;
        public string label { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Document
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Datedoc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Datedel { get; set; }
    }
```

`EF` automatically can detect the `foreign key` and there is no need to write any code, but if you would like to handle it manually and have control over this, it could be like below :

```
builder.Entity<Docuemnt>(e =>
        {
       e.HasOne(x => x.Category).WithMany(x => x.Documents).HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId).IsRequired(false);
 });
```

Comment: If I modify the model like this and run add-migration command, it will update my Database and add new field and foreign key ? I don't want to modify the database structure because it used by other application. I want linked the model without impact the database.

Comment: The link between these two modele is Category.code (And not the ID fields) <-> Document.catcode. The aim of this is to display on the same page, the document's information and the label of the document's category.

Comment: Thanks for you help your answer was very close to the solution for me. I just had to add .hasPrincipalKey in the context to specify the field used to map the data.